# Mostrar o resultado de uma variável JS através do Jquery em um input no html

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde!
Estou fazendo um jogo simples de jokenpô

Eu criei três inputs, um para inserir o valor que usuário quer e outro para mostrar o que foi selecionado pelo programa e por ultimo um para mostrar o resultado.

Eu consegui pegar o valor do usuário e mostrar no html o valor do programa, mas não estou conseguindo mostrar o resultado no último input? Qual seria a maneira certa?

```
var textoUser = $("#txtFieldUser");
var textoGanhador = $("txtFieldGanhador");


var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "Pedra";

} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "Papel";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Tesoura";
} 

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var resultado = null;

  var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 === choice2)
            return ("O resultado é um empate!");
        else if (choice1 === "pedra") {
            if (choice2 === "tesoura")
                return ("pedra vence");
            else {
                return ("papel vence");
            }
        }
        else if (choice1 === "papel") {
            if (choice2 === "pedra")
                return "papel vence";
            else {
                return "tesoura vence";
            }
        }
        else if (choice1 === "tesoura") {
            if (choice2 === "pedra")
                return "pedra vence";
            else {
                return "tesoura vence";
            }
        }
    };


  compare(textoUser, computerChoice);
```

Comment: Poste seu codigo para facilitar

Answer (score -1):

```js
var textoUser = $("#txtFieldUser");
var textoGanhador = $("txtFieldGanhador");


var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "Pedra";

} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "Papel";
} else {
computerChoice = "Tesoura";
} 

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var resultado = null;

  var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2)
        return ("O resultado é um empate!");
    else if (choice1 === "pedra") {
        if (choice2 === "tesoura")
            return ("pedra vence");
        else {
            return ("papel vence");
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "papel") {
        if (choice2 === "pedra")
            return "papel vence";
        else {
            return "tesoura vence";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "tesoura") {
        if (choice2 === "pedra")
            return "pedra vence";
        else {
            return "tesoura vence";
        }
    }
};


  compare(textoUser, computerChoice);
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenho essa pagina que eu criei como sugestão para você

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Sua escolha</h2>
    <select id="op" onchange="joken()">
        <option value=99>Escolha</option>
        <option value=0>Pedra</option>
        <option value=1>Papel</option>
        <option value=2>Tesoura</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <span id="bot"></span>
    <h1>Resultado : <br><span id="result"></span></h1>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function joken() {
        var op = $("select option:selected").val();
        var bot = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        var array = ["Pedra","Papel","Tesoura"];


        if (op != 99) {
            $("#bot").html(array[bot]);
            if (op == bot) {
                $("#result").html("Empate !");
            }else if (op == 0 && bot == 2) {
                $("#result").html("Voce Venceu !");
            }else if (op == 2 && bot == 1) {
                $("#result").html("Voce Venceu !");
            }else if (op == 1 && bot == 0) {
                $("#result").html("Voce Venceu !");
            }else{
                $("#result").html("Voce Perdeu !");
            }
        }else{

        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function Jogar(Voce){
 var radom = Math.random(); 
 if(radom <= 0.3){
  var Maquina = "Pedra";
 } else if(radom <= 0.6){
  var Maquina = "Papel";
 } else {
  var Maquina = "Tesoura";
 }

 if(Maquina === Voce){
  alert("Empate!");
 } 
 /* Você vence se: */
 else if(Maquina === "Pedra" && Voce === "Papel"){
  alert("Você Venceu pois escolheu papel e a maquina pedra!");
 }
 else if(Maquina === "Papel" && Voce === "Tesoura"){
  alert("Você Venceu pois escolheu tesoura e a maquina papel!");
 }
 else if(Maquina === "Tesoura" && Voce === "Pedra"){
  alert("Você Venceu pois escolheu pedra e a maquina tesoura!");
 }
 /* Maquina vence se: */
 else if(Maquina === "Papel" && Voce === "Pedra"){
  alert("Maquina Venceu pois escolheu Papel e você pedra!");
 }
 else if(Maquina === "Tesoura" && Voce === "Papel"){
  alert("Maquina Venceu pois escolheu tesoura e você papel!");
 }
 else if(Maquina === "Pedra" && Voce === "Tesoura"){
  alert("Maquina Venceu pois escolheu Pedra e você tesoura!");
 }

}

Jogar("Pedra");
```

Answer (score -2):

Seria mais ou menos isso que você quer?

```js
$('#seu').on('blur', function(){
  var valor = $(this).val()
  var valorMaquina = "Tesoura"
  $('#maquina').val(valorMaquina)
  var resultado = ''
  if(valor == "Pedra"){
    resultado = 'Você ganhou'
    $('#resultado').val(resultado)  
  }else{
    resultado = 'Maquina ganhou'
    $('#resultado').val(resultado)
  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="seu" placeholder="Você">
<input type="text" id="maquina" placeholder="Maquina">
<input type="text" id="resultado" placeholder="Resultado">
```